# submit() is not working with Selenium API

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to submit the form with selenium api submit(). Click() would not work definitely because it is form button.
Element is "submit".
element.submit() but nothing is happening.
I am trying some java script solution to submit form.
Here is the html:

```
<form class="ng-pristinedfgd ngrg-valid">
<label class="input-width" for="userName">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="input-width form-input " name="userName" autocomplete="off">
<label class="input-width" for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="input-width form-input " name="password" autocomplete="off">
<p class="forgot-utility">Need login help? Visit the utility website for direction.</p>
<button type="**submit**" class="blue-button">Share Energy Usage</button
</form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not FormButton.submit(), it's `FormElement.submit()`.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you can invoke `click()` method as follows:

- *Java `click()`*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='blue-button'][contains(.,'Share Energy Usage')]")).click();
  ```

**Note**: As the *AUT* is [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) based so if you are trying to invoke `click()` soon after *Page Load* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@class='ng-pristinedfgd ngrg-valid']//button[@class='blue-button'][contains(.,'Share Energy Usage')]"))).click();
```

Comment: @Mini It wasn't a suggestion but a well researched answer. However `did not work` doesn't throws any light on what's wrong happening. Update the answer with your current code trials along with the error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can always use JS when this happens (it's kind of frequent in some applications) -

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('blue-button')[0].click()")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call via following:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("blue-button")).click();
```

and as @Debanjan mentioned introduce wait.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your valuable time. I tried many options but did not work because there was extra margin on that button so Selenium was keep on loosing focus even after intentional focus on element. As I asked developer to remove the extra CSS margin on that button, issue got resolved.